# Why does JWT Cookie get removed on page refresh

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, fetch

Why does the JWT Cookie disappear on page refresh?

- I'm using Fetch to make a request
- it initially sets the JWT cookie which I verify on Chrome Inspector
- on page refresh, the cookie disappears. No specific errors are being logged.

Here's the frontend request:

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form_email = $('#email').val(); 
    var form_password = $('#password').val(); 
    
    var formData = {
        email:form_email, 
        password:form_password,
    } 

    const url = $(form).attr('action');
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email:form_email, 
            password:form_password
            }),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        credentials:'include'
    }

    fetch(url,options)
        .then(function(response) {
       console.log(response); 
         }) 
});
```

On the server-side, I already have enabled CORS, set credentials to being true, and the origin.

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();

connectDB();


 
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'https://zkarimi.com'}));
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
```

Here's how I handle the JWT signing and cookie response:

```
jwt.sign(
    payload,
    config.get("jwtSecret"),
    { expiresIn: 36000 },
    (err, token) => {
      if (err) throw err;
  res.cookie('jwt',token, { httpOnly: true ,secure: true, sameSite:'None',maxAge: 3600000 })

  
       res.json({user_email:email }); 
    }
  );
```

Lastly here's the response from the initial request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://zkarimi.com
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNWZjODA1Zjk2MDRlNjEwMDE3NzQwZWUxIn0sImlhdCI6MTYwNzAyMjg5MSwiZXhwIjoxNjA3MDU4ODkxfQ.oXuA6DfdZbO2XW5HtLR44pVgGUWsXMyaV-l0iVeF7to; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 03 Dec 2020 20:14:51 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 30
Etag: W/"1e-vu/QJUeZrcotU6SR/PRLtu/c6Jw"
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 19:14:51 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

After this request ^, refreshing the page removes the cookie from Application > Storage > Cookies and subsequent authentication requests indicate there's no JWT cookie.

Comment: Since it looks like CORS is involved: there's no way to have your app on a domain and send/receive cookies to/from another domain. My guess is that you host your app in a domain `A`, you send an authentication ajax request to another domain `B`, the ajax request comes back with a cookie set on `B` but you expect it to be set on `A`. It is not set and will never be. The only way to handle it is to send the token in a custom header rather than in a regular cookie.

Comment: Interesting. I've just started noticing a similar issue on my local dev box this morning. 
I'll post back if I find anything more.
Server request sets the cookie successfully and I can see it in dev tools, but then after reloading the page the cookie is just gone, I double checked the expiry and that was fine too...

Comment: Were you doing the redirect immediately, or near enough after the call that set the cookie?
I added a timeout just to see what would happen and setTimeout(redirect, 50); solved this for me, it's gross and I don't like it but it worked :|